# React Bootstrap - 'openModal' is not defined no-undef

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

When a button is clicked I want a modal to be opened. I have implemented the code but I am thrown errors and I cannot figure out why. Here is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import {
    Modal,
    Button,
    Card,
    CardHeader,
    CardBody,
    CardTitle,
    CardFooter,
    Table,
    Row,
    ButtonGroup,
    Col,
  } from "reactstrap";

  function Table() {
    state = {
      isOpen: false
    };
    openModal = () => this.setState({ isOpen: true });
    closeModal = () => this.setState({ isOpen: false });

  return (
      <>
        <div className="contentGroup">
          <Row>
            <Col md="12">
              <Card>
                    <CardHeader>
                    <ButtonGroup style={{float: 'right'}}>
                        <Button className="btn-round btn-icon" color="blue" onClick={this.openModal} style={{float: 'right'}}>
                            <i className="icon-plus-add"/>
                        </Button>
                    </ButtonGroup>
                   </CardHeader>
                       ...
             </Card>
             <Modal show={this.state.isOpen} onHide={this.closeModal}>
              <Modal.Header closeButton>
              <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
              </Modal.Header>
              <Modal.Body>Modal text</Modal.Body>
              <Modal.Footer>
              <Button color="info" onClick={this.closeModal}>
                Close
              </Button>
              </Modal.Footer>
              </Modal>
          </Col>
        </Row>
     </div>
    </>
   );
  }

export default Table;
```

In console I am getting the following errors:

```
'state' is not defined       no-undef     
'openModal' is not defined   no-undef 
'closeModal' is not defined  no-undef
```

Yet I am not sure why. Any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to change the name of the component to `CustomTable` as you already have `Table` being imported from `reactstrap` to avoid name collision.

We should not be using `this` inside the functional component so change your code to make use of the `hooks` .

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
    Modal,
    Button,
    Card,
    CardHeader,
    CardBody,
    CardTitle,
    CardFooter,
    Table,
    Row,
    ButtonGroup,
    Col,
  } from "reactstrap";

  function CustomTable() {

  const [ isOpen , setIsOpen ] = useState(false);
    

  const openModal = () =>  setIsOpen(true);

  const closeModal = () => setIsOpen(false);

  return (
      <>
        <div className="contentGroup">
          <Row>
            <Col md="12">
              <Card>
                    <CardHeader>
                    <ButtonGroup style={{float: 'right'}}>
                        <Button className="btn-round btn-icon" color="blue" onClick={openModal} style={{float: 'right'}}>
                            <i className="icon-plus-add"/>
                        </Button>
                    </ButtonGroup>
                   </CardHeader>
                       ...
             </Card>
             <Modal show={isOpen} onHide={closeModal}>
              <Modal.Header closeButton>
              <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
              </Modal.Header>
              <Modal.Body>Modal text</Modal.Body>
              <Modal.Footer>
              <Button color="info" onClick={closeModal}>
                Close
              </Button>
              </Modal.Footer>
              </Modal>
          </Col>
        </Row>
     </div>
    </>
   );
  }

export default CustomTable;
```

Comment: Now I am getting a different error: `React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.` This is whenever I click the button

Comment: Looks like you have the conflict with names , change the name of your component to `CustomTable` , as you already have imported `Table` from `reactstrap`

Comment: Sadly the issue is still there. I have tried changing names and changing imports in my routes.js but it keeps throwing that error and `'Check your code at Tasks.js:94-98` (which is the lines of <Modal>)

Comment: Your error screenshot tells the error is from the Tasks.js component . Can you add the code for the component as well ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236460/discussion-between-shyam-and-noobcode0000).